# BenQ monitor goes black when switching from Windows to OSX

Tags: display, bootcamp

I have two MBPs.  I have been running bootcamp on one to do some Windows-only work.  It is a 13" from 2020 running macOS 10.15.6.  I have 16" 2019, running macOS 12.4.  I also have a BenQ GL2780 external monitor.  I connect either laptop to the monitor through an Anker A8383 hub.

I have noticed the following problem when switching between operating systems.  When I switch from Windows/bootcamp to a macOS (literally unplug one laptop and plug in the other) MBP, the BenQ display is detected by macOS but remains black.  I can see it when I open System Preferences -> Displays, it just won't show anything.  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Rebooting the Windows MBP into macOS allows the monitor to work.  Rebooting the other MBP and then plugging in the BenQ monitor also allows the monitor to work.  I'd guess this is an interaction with macOS and the BenQ because Windows always works with the BenQ (at least, I haven't been able to get a black screen) but macOS appears more fussy.  Maybe it needs to talk to the BenQ and reconfigure it for macOS, and it only does that once on boot, I'm not sure.

Comment: Exactly. Set the monitor to not scan inputs and always just listen to the source you know the Mac will use. Is there an adapter or cable that might be blocking EDID if you are going direct HDMI from the Mac to the display with no adapters.

Comment: It is certainly possible that the Anker A8383 is doing something.  Unfortunately, my MBPs are all USB-C only and the BenQ is HDMI 1.4 | DisplayPort | DVI | VGA.  I have to go through some kind of adapter and that can be hit or miss.  When the BenQ is disconnected from the computers, I can chose the input, but plugging it in after doesn't help.  When the BenQ is connected, I can't find any way to select an input.

Comment: Aah, yeah so the signaling on a USB dock might be less good than a thunderbolt dock. I don’t have any benq and we just started getting some anker “hubs” to test.